# Is it possible to adapt a running class dynamically using reflection?

Tags: java, class, dynamic, reflection

Assume I have a Class 'ABC' which is running and has only one method, say run().

Using reflection, i want to check if 'ABC' has a method called 'walk()'. Since 'ABC' does not have 'walk()', the search will return negative. But is it possible for me to dynamically add a plugin or update 'ABC' to include 'walk()' method (say from a plugin repository)? I do not want to stop 'ABC', but rather adapt it to serve requests on the fly..possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. What you are looking for is called "bytecode instrumentation". You can do it on classload-time and pass the modified bytecode to the classloader or save the modified classes to disk. It's done with e.g. the javassist library.

For an example how to modify a method look at http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html, but it's also possible to add new methods.